# How to turn an array of elements into strings and parse them using javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing

Now that I have an array of  elements. I want to turn them into array of strings and parse out the information after onclick. So i guess I have two questions, first is how to turn them into strings second is how to use regex to parse them? I can write the regex myself but I want to know how to apply it to the string in javascript.

First I did this:

```
var array = $('a[onclick*="findCustomer"]');
```

Now, I have a list of this:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="findCustomer('James Smith',808-371-   4984,"Hawaii")">James Smith</a>
```

So my question is how to turn it into an array of string and how to parse out the Customer's name, phone number and state from that.

Comment: Parse what information? Are these elements form fields, and you want the values? Divs with element data? Need more details, sample HTML would be helpful.

Comment: Please read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1615483) about why you **should not** try to parse x/html with regex

Comment: `808-371-   4984` is not surounded with quotes and `Hawaii` is but with double quotes which are already around, so backslash them or put simple quotes.

Comment: @BaliBalo a backslash is not an escape character in HTML (as it is in JavaScript). You would have to encode the `"`s to `&quot;` or `&#34;` and encode `'` as `&#39;` (for safety).

Comment: Yeah you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is how to turn it into an array of string and how to parse out the Customer's name, phone number and state from that.

First get all the *onclick* attributes (as you seem to want to use jQuery, this can be done using [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/))

```
var array = $.map($('a[onclick*="findCustomer"]'), function (elm) {
    return elm.getAttribute('onclick');
}); // `array` is now an array of the _onclick_ attributes
```

Then parse the attribute, for example with [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$.each(array, function (key, val) {
    var parts = val.slice(val.indexOf('(')+1, val.lastIndexOf(')')).split(',');
    // parts[0] is name, parts[1] is number, parts[2] is state
    // you'll need to trim quotes
});
```

It is a really bad idea to try to parse x/HTML with RegExp as [**explained here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1615483). The method I've shown should be okay as you **know** the structure of the *onclick* attribute.
A much better solution, however, would be to have this data accessible via some other method which does not involve parsing HTML at all.